# SPA implementation

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I want to implement spa in my angularjs code , do I need to create all my template URL files in the same folder as the base controller file?

The structure of my project is

```
app-----
      Views ---
Public ---
       Js---
            Base.js
```

What will be the file structure if I want to implement SPA?
Ex:

```
 sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',

    function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Angular',{
        templateUrl : '/Angular.html',
        controller: 'AngularController'
    }).
    when("/Node", {
        templateUrl: '/Node.html',
        controller: 'NodeController'
    });
}]);
```

.  This code is in my base.js

Then where should I create Angular.html and Node.html in my current file structure?
If I want to follow my current file structure itself, then how do I point the 'templateURL' to that file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angularjs, I will suggest to have a look or clone the project at [AngularJs](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed). You will get the basic understanding on routing and folder structure.